# Why does stringr::str_replace() match every character in a string as "."?

Tags: r

```
library(stringr)
y4=c("yes i do")
str_replace_all(y4,".","_")
[1] "________"

str_replace_all(y4," ","_")
[1] "yes_i_do"

y4=c("yes i do.")
str_replace_all(y4," ","_")
[1] "yes_i_do."
```

If you attempt to replace "." in a string, every character is replaced.

Comment: The documentation states that the pattern argument is interpreted: `The default interpretation is a regular expression, as described in stringi::stringi-search-regex. `. In regular expressions, `.` is a special character that represents any character. The documentation goes on to explain how to have the pattern argument interpreted literally, not as a regular expression.

Comment: `.` being a wildcard character isn't unique to this function or to `stringr`, or even to R, but is the case in most (all?) regex implementations

Answer (score 1):

`stringr` by default uses regular expressions (regex), a powerful searching tool. The `.` is a regex wildcard for any character except a new line. If you want a literal `.` you have to escape it with a backslash like so `\.` in regex, but as R interprets the string we need another backslash to escape the first backslash so you use `\\.`

[Obligatory xkcd](https://www.xkcd.com/1638/)

For your example:

```
library(stringr)
y4 <- c("yes i do.") #added a period so we can see the replacement.
str_replace_all(y4,"\\.","_")
[1] "yes i do_"
```

Alternately, if you wanted to use a `fixed` expression without regex syntax you could use:

```
str_replace_all(y4, fixed("."),"_")
[1] "yes i do_"
```